# Qualifying a temporary table column name in jOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I am using jOOQ with a temporary table:

```
Table<Record> TMP = DSL.table("tmp");
Field<String> TYPE = DSL.field("type", String.class);
Field<String> TOKEN = DSL.field("token", String.class);
```

This allows me to write simple queries:
    DSL.select(TYPE, TOKEN).from(TMP)...

However, when I try to join against another table, it creates ambiguities because the column names `TYPE` and `TOKEN` are not qualified with a table name (i.e. I need the generated code to look like `SELECT tmp.type, tmp.token ...`). Is there a way to make this happen, either by making Jooq understand that the temp table has certain columns, or by making a `Field` with a qualified name?

Of course I can always drop to raw SQL for these parts of the query, which is what I've been doing so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to interact with tables / columns dynamically (i.e. without using the code generator) in jOOQ:

#### Using plain SQL (`org.jooq.SQL`)

That's what you're doing. You can obviously qualify the columns directly in your plain SQL `Field` references in two ways:

By repeating the `"tmp"` string in each field:

```
Table<Record> TMP = DSL.table("tmp");
Field<String> TYPE = DSL.field("tmp.type", String.class);
Field<String> TOKEN = DSL.field("tmp.token", String.class);
```

By embedding the `"tmp"` reference in the plain SQL template:

```
Table<Record> TMP = DSL.table("tmp");
Field<String> TYPE = DSL.field("{0}.type", String.class, TMP);
Field<String> TOKEN = DSL.field("{0}.token", String.class, TMP);
```

[The plain SQL functionality is documented here in the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/)

#### Using qualified references (`org.jooq.Name`)

That's probably what you want to be doing instead. You'll write:

```
Table<Record> TMP = DSL.table(DSL.name("tmp"));
Field<String> TYPE = DSL.field(DSL.name("tmp", "type"), String.class);
Field<String> TOKEN = DSL.field(DSL.name("tmp", "token"), String.class);
```

[The naming functionality is described here in the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names/).

The advantages of this approach are:

- [No SQL injection risk](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/sql-injection/)
- Case-sensitivity is taken care of
- [Table mapping and other AST transformations will work, too](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/runtime-schema-mapping/)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for writing such a clear and thorough answer!