# postgres and jooq use fields of sql created temporary table

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I created a temporary table using sql:

```
jooq.query("CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp(" +
                "date timestamp without time zone not null, " +
                "id bigint");").execute();
```

However when I try to use one of the fields of the table I got a npe

```
jooq.select().from(another_table)
             .innerJoin(table("tmp")).on(another_table.id.eq(table("tmp").field("id", Long.class))).fetch();
```

How can I access the fields of the temporary table?

Comment: My current version is PostgreSQL 9.5.19

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qualifying a temporary table column name in jOOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657391/qualifying-a-temporary-table-column-name-in-jooq)

Comment: Instead of `table("tmp").field("id", Long.class)` you have to use `field(name("tmp", "id"), Long.class)`.